# Nintex Workflows in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, nintex-workflow

I've been working with creating a brand new Nintex workflow on an existing sharepoint 2010 site for the last week and I've been experiencing a lot of issues.

I'm curious to know if these are inherent in the platform or is down to some configuration of my tools/environment.

I don't know the details of the server really ( other than it's sharepoint 2010)  but I'm editing the workflows directly in the browser using IE 11 (.0.9600.18097)
(I also happen to be running the browser from a Windows Server 2008 R2 Data center machine)

The kind of problems I'm seeing are:

1. When I insert a new 'Set Variable' Node I can't configure it until I save,exit the workflow and open it again.
2. Similarly when using the 'Run if' when I select a workflow data the dropdown values don't populate until I save the changes to the node then re-open it.
3. When using the Notification Node I can't select a variable to use as the to field.. the dialog opens and I can select the item I want but clicking OK does nothing.
4. In general the rendering of the workflow tree can get a little 'funky' and infrequently I've noticed nodes  I've just created and saved have disappeared

I can see that when I bring up the developer tools IE is running in 'IE 8' emulation mode, but forcing  'Edge' or '10' seems to make little difference.

It still works but it takes me much longer to complete a task than I would expect.
I've not seen anyone else report this kind of issues so I'm guessing either I've missed something fundamental ( do folks edit them from Visual Studio primarily? )
or there's something a bit off about my local setup.

Comment: That sounds like abnormal behavior. I'd bring your problem directly to Nintex support: https://community.nintex.com/community/support

Answer (score 1):

Putting the browser into IE8 emulation mode is standard Sharepoint 2010 behaviour. Your issues do sound strange, they are certainly not typical.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some kind of firewall that us blocking some JavaScript Ajax calls?

Comment: I don't think so, there doesn't seem to be anything in the javascript console, but I'll double check the http response list see if I'm seeing any funny  response codes or timeouts.